# How to rename wordpress Widget

Tags: widgets

I want to rename "Widget" to something else

Like "Block" or something else.

please help me.

**EDIT**

Per the user's comment below, she wants to change `class="widget"` to `class="block"` (or any arbitrary class name) in the rendered, sidebar Widget.

Comment: We need **considerably** more information, if we are to hope to help you here...

Comment: want to rename "class="widget" to class="Block" in sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes assigned to rendered Widgets are specified by the argument array passed to the [`register_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) call used to register the sidebar. e.g.:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'name'          => sprintf(__('Sidebar %d'), $i ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-$i',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>' ); 
?>
```

See the `before_widget` parameter:

```
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">'
```

...change it accordingly, e.g. to:

```
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="block %2$s">'
```